# Have TypeScript infer the right generic type

Tags: typescript

I have the following simplified code that fails to infer `Set<number>` for the `inner` property:

```js
function test<S>(state: S, fn: (value: { outer: Set<S> }) => void) {}
function numberFn(value: { outer: Set<{ inner: Set<number> }> }) {}
test({ inner: new Set() }, numberFn)
//     ^____
// Type 'Set<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Set<number>'.
//   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

In my real code I have many calls like `test` and with different types for the generic type parameter of `Set`, and at the moment those types are not exported, so it would be a pain if I had to explicitly type them. I had hoped TypeScript could infer them, but I have been unable to get it to do so.

I wrote some tests to further my understanding and see if I could get to infer the right type.

```js
function test1<T>(input: { arr: T[] }, value: { val: T }) {}
test1({ arr: [] }, { val: 5 })
// function test1<number>(input: {
//   arr: number[];
// }, value: {
//   val: number;
// }): void
```

That works. However this doesn't:

```js
function test2<T>(input: { arr: Array<T> }, value: { val: T }) {}
test2({ arr: new Array() }, { val: 5 })
// function test2<any>(input: {
//   arr: any[];
// }, value: {
//   val: any;
// }): void
```

Probably to do with `[]` having special support over generic types in general. Confusingly enough when I try it with `Set` rather than `Array` and reverse the argument order, it does infer the right type:

```js
function test3<T>(value: { val: T }, input: { arr: Set<T> }) {}
test3({ val: 5 }, { arr: new Set() })
// function test3<number>(value: {
//   val: number;
// }, input: {
//   arr: Set<number>;
// }): void
```

I can workaround it by do the inferring it for TypeScript explicitly, but this gets ugly, like so:

```js
function test<S>(state: S, fn: (value: { outer: Set<S> }) => void) {}
function numberFn(value: { outer: Set<{ inner: Set<number> }> }) {}
test(
  { inner: new Set() } as Parameters<typeof numberFn>[0] extends { outer: Set<infer S> } ? S : never,
  numberFn,
)
```

Can I rewrite my code such that TypeScript can infer the right type for state, like it does in `test3` (the one using `Set` with reversed arguments)?

Comment: Hmm, I doubt this is going to work. TS only knows about the generic type arg `{inner: Set<number>}` by inspecting the second argument, which it then needs to use *contextually* for interpreting the first argument. Simultaneous generic type arg and contextual type inference isn't always possible (see [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599)) but where it is possible it generally needs to progress from left to right (infer stuff from previous args). If you can't refactor even to reverse the argument order, then there are only workarounds, like `{ inner: new Set<any>() }`

Comment: I can refactor all I want, if that is what needed to make it work. Just using `any` is definitely better than my cast. Thanks for the link, it clarifies some things!

Comment: Shall I write up a full answer explaining the issue?  Or am I missing something about the situation?

Comment: Thanks, I would like that. I have edited my question with more context in case it helps answering.

Comment: Got it working by changing `rewrites: []` to `rewrites: new Array()`. No idea why though. I thought the semantics should be the same in this case, that `[]` should be an alias for `new Array()`. Maybe `Array` has a default generic of `any` and `[]` of `never`, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond since you're talking about code from your second snippet which isn't a [mre] I can look at in my IDE.   But no, `[]` is not an alias for `new Array()`, at least not in the type system.  `[]` is an array literal whose type is auto-evolving, while `new Array()` mostly produces an `Array<any>` only.  If you're trying to block inference from the first param you can do it.  Both of these are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NdJEyW).  But I'm a bit worried that the scope of the question is expanding to everything around inference so I'm hoping not to go into every example

Comment: If it doesn't help you, you can safely ignore it, but my remarks apply just as well too my minimal examples. If you put your comments into an answer I will accept it. As they did answer my question. Learned some new things, thanks! I will have to experiment some more with the evolving type of `[]` as most my code makes it default to `never[]` requiring explicit typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, TypeScript cannot reliably infer both [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and the [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) simultaneously.  In your call to `test()`, you need the type argument for `S` to be inferred from `numberFn`, which then implies that the argument `{inner: new Set()}` should be checked against `{inner: Set<number>}`, meaning that `new Set()` should be interpreted in the context of `Set<number>`, meaning that the type argument for the `Set` constructor should be inferred as `number`.  But unfortunately the inference algorithm doesn't do things in this order.  Somewhere along the way the compiler just gives up on contextual typing for `state`, meaning that inference of the `Set` constructor's type argument fails, and it falls back to `unknown`.  `Set<unknown>` is not assignable to `Set<number>` (it has some *contravariant* methods, as described in [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)) and it explodes.

```
function test<S>(state: S, fn: (value: { outer: Set<S> }) => void) { return state; }      

function numberFn(value: { outer: Set<{ inner: Set<number> }> }) { }

test({ inner: new Set() }, numberFn) // error
//     ~~~~~
// 'Set<unknown>' is not assignable to 'Set<number>'
```

This problem of simultaneous generic and contextual inference is a general limitation of TypeScript.  The most relevant open issue about this is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599). There has been steady improvement in support for this over the years, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538), but there will unfortunately always be unsupported cases.

---

By far the easiest approach is for you to work around it and use `Set<any>` instead of `Set<unknown>`, since `any` is intentionally looser than `unknown`. Note that I modified `test()` to return `state` so you can see that `S` is still inferred as `{inner: Set<number>}`, and therefore the returned value is of type `Set<number>` (and not as `Set<any>`):

```
const inner = test({ inner: new Set<any>() }, numberFn).inner; // okay
//    ^? const inner: Set<number>;
```

If you care more about inference than that, the only way I can think of which gives you the requisite control is to break apart `test()` into pieces by [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) it:

```
function curryTest<S>(fn: (value: { outer: Set<S> }) => void) {
    return (state: S) => {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Now `curryTest()` only accepts `fn` and that will infer `S`.  It returns a new function which only accepts `state`, and at that point, `S` is set in stone.  There is no *simultaneous* inference happening here:

```
const inner2 = curryTest(numberFn)({ inner: new Set() }).inner; // okay
//    ^? const inner2: Set<number>;
```

You might be able to get similar behavior in a non-curried function by reordering arguments, as certain aspects of the inference algorithm work from left to right in the argument list.  But if not, this is always an option.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgMoD4AUGAhqgFyLYA0iwY5+AbkQDYgrkDeicIqATuWwoseRAF8AlIgC8uRAzgwAJlK59hIPkmKoA3OIBQoSLASIwIALYAjFHwBiYRizaduvO4OGYuMMGE8KbwsbOzkxcNVDA1QMfF9-QICAdyCofCkxahDbBzApAHoCxDs+OD4DIsRq6oA-evrK4oByISxwAGswOGSwXGbEGDRzOChEIjQ0GABzMCJrZhRkOERW4Ktc-oNtiAQMQcS+GWR0dISAgXMUVLbMIjAATwJM7I27RwkAOj8L-Sq4DpEB5NGqIAB6AH4DD87J8iEolPgAIwABgkumhh0+wHKAFEiBAABaMGRyXZgNBwRafZhwabIlEoxAAWnkEnRiCqAE4UdtjNB4EgIJo+A8ACqnHAEWj0JisdiILg8fheESRUnyRQqRUGUHqKCaJCEKAkBXYKSyHWgvUaLSIHQoDGgsQGF3k-YwvgAJmOwr4oolcRy73y8QOF3IKTSGXEX09f2KAKBIJqkO2QA)